# Manipulando string php

Tags: php

Queria conseguir acessar algumas informações desta string:

```
{"op":"&","c":[{"type":"completion","cm":1227,"e":1}],"showc":[true]}
```

ela me parece um array, porém ela imprime como string, como faria para acessar o cm: 1227?

alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: é um json, da um `json_decode()` que isso vira um objeto

Comment: Obrigado, transformei ele em um objeto, como faria agora, para acessar as informações?

Comment: `echo $var->op` use os nomes das propriedades eles estão do lado esquerdo dos dois pontos.